# Find x,y axis of element in reportlab

Tags: pdf, reportlab

I'm fairly new to using reportlab. 
I have something like the following.

```
s = []
document = BaseDocTemplate('test.pdf', pagesize=A4)
s.append(Paragraph("test1"))
s.append(Paragraph("test2"))
s.append(Paragraph("test3"))
document.build(s)
```

Is if there's a way to find x,y axis of any of the paragraphs appended? Should I be using Canvas for this?